# Jquery/AJAX wordpress, How to pass this input array data from jquery to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have multiple input fields of checkboxes and textboxes. I want to post the data of the textboxes respective to the selected checkboxes.

Here's the scenario: I'm making an add to cart page. If one checkbox is checked, it will then retrieve the values from the textbox with the same key as the checkbox. Checkboxes and textboxes are created dynamically in PHP while fetching data from the database.

I've named each checkboxes in an array manner as well as the textboxes like this name="checkbox[1]" and name="textbox[1]" and so on.

The thing is, i cannot pass that data through jquery/ajax. I've tried using .map() function together with .get() function but still of no use. .serialize() isn't working for me as well. This is done in a wordpress plugin, Thanks.

```
HTML: <input type='check' name='checkbox[1]' value='' />

<input type='text' name='textbox[1]' value='' />
<input type='check' name='checkbox[2]' value='' />
<input type='text' name='textbox[2]' value='' />
```

Comment: Pls put you code next time

Answer (score 0):

```
var dataFromInput1 = $( "input[value='textbox[1]']" ).val;
var dataFromInput2 = $( "input[value='textbox[2]']" ).val;
var dataFromInput3 = $( "input[value='textbox[3]']" ).val;

$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "../WebService.php",
      data: { 'data1': dataFromInput1,'data2': dataFromInput2,'data3': dataFromInput3 },
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json"

  });
```